# How do I edit the input fields of paypal sandbox?

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
      <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
      <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="QHHYRZWR44QMY">
      <table>
             <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="WeBoss - Downpayment">WeBoss - Downpayment</td></tr>
             <tr><td><select name="os0">
                           <option value="Combat">Combat P1,000.00 PHP</option>
                           <option value="Battlefield">Battlefield P1,500.00 PHP</option>
                           <option value="Warfield">Warfield P2,100.00 PHP</option>
                     </select> </td></tr>
      </table>
      <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="PHP">
      <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynow_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
      <a href="func/unsetcancel.php" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
      <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

i would like to edit the price, how would i do that? and also i tried in "BUY NOW" button and change amount but still it wont change the price.

is there a way to edit the paypal sandbox page?

Comment: You are using a hosted button - `<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="QHHYRZWR44QMY">`. So you will need to edit that button. Also, according to https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_xclick_options_help_outside - `Option fields cannot be used for options that will alter the item's price`. see also https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/helpcenter/article/?solutionId=11603&topicID=11500038&m=TCI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a hosted buttons, you cannot dynamically change the amount in the code.
To be able to change the amount in the code, use a non-hosted button instead. To create a non-hosted button, log in to your paypal.com account to re-create the button again, but this time, click on Step 2 and un-check the option to save button at PayPal. After clicking on 'create button' click on 'remove code protection' to get a clear-text button code.

NB. However, using a clear-text button code is un-secure as someone can change the values in the code prior to submission of the button.

So instead, you can use 'BMCreateButton API' to dynamically create hosted or encrypted buttons.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/button-manager/BMCreateButton_API_Operation_NVP/

Samples http://paypal.github.io/sample-apps/  [Classic API Samples]